# How can I include a port in my domain?

Tags: dns, port, portforwarding

Maybe I ask this question in a weird way, but I'll explain my goal here:

I'd like to let my domain example.com point to my ip 1.2.3.4.5:42, so for example (not the real reason) if I have a Minecraft server hosted at home on port 42, people don't have to typ example.com:42, but just typ example.com. I know normally it points to port 80, but I know for a fact that what I try to accomplish is at least possible.

I myself use Windows server 2012, but for future use and other users maybe it's a good idea to try answering this question for both Windows and Linux.

Subquestion: Why shouldn't I run my application on port 80, just like Teamviewer does?

Comment: Not only is this not on-topic for StackOverflow, but not achievable with TCP/IP

Comment: you can use iptables/firewald/router on your main server to redirect/NAT all request to port 80 to your home computer at port 42.so your end user sees everything is coming from your main server

Comment: @Rowland Shaw I'm sorry if it's offtopic, but it is for my application so I really thought that it was ontopic. I just simplified my question and said it was for Minecraft, but this is not the case.

Comment: `example.com` doesn't necessarily imply port 80, although `http://example.com` does. If you connect to `example.com` from within Minecraft, it will use its default port, which is 25565. Remember that the protocol implies the (default) port, so `ftp://example.com` implies `example.com:21`, so `minecraft://example.com` implies `example.com:25565`.

Comment: first of all tell us which protocol are you planning on the main server?

Comment: you can run anything on any port as long as it is available (not used by another application)

Comment: Well it's just a plain c# client/server socket connection as seen in [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463947/Working-with-Sockets-in-Csharp)

Comment: @user2754599 in which case your c# client should just default to whatever "default port number" you chose for your application, but allow it to be overridden if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - DNS entries (with the exception of `SRV` records) have no concept of port-numbers.

If your actual application is HTTP rather than Minecraft you can use a `3xx` redirect code from a web server running on the default port to push users to the non-standard port.  However most other protocols don't actually have any such redirect mechanism.

Comment: @user2754599 yes, except that the URL in the `Location:` header also needs to include the `:port` field.  You could also use `mod_rewrite` instead of an actual page (or PHP script, which is what you've suggested).